# Memory leak when watching a windows service status with a timer and System.ServiceProcess

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, windows-services

I'm using a timer and the System.ServiceProcess namespace to check the status of a windows service. I'm doing it successfully but the memory usage of the application keeps going up. Here's my code, what am i missing here? the service controller is already in a using block.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    servicetimer.AutoReset = True
    servicetimer.Interval = 1
    AddHandler servicetimer.Elapsed, AddressOf tick
    servicetimer.Enabled = True
    servicetimer.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    Using sc As New ServiceController("Smart Card")
        If sc.Status = ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped Or sc.Status = ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending Then
            'Do stuff when stopped
        ElseIf sc.Status = ServiceControllerStatus.Running Or sc.Status = ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending Then
            'Do Stuff when started
        Else

        End If
    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure the leak isn't in the "do stuff" part of the code?  (In other words, have you reproduced the problem with *just* the code shown above?)

Comment: @HarryJohnston the "do stuff" part is currently just setting a labels text to show the current status of the service, i've removed it to check and the leak still happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is a bit embarrassing. There was no memory leak, when i start the application the memory usage keeps going up which I thought was a memory leak so I tried to stop it from happening, turns out it was normal and stops growing after a while.